# Issue on naming Rdata Fila Load

Tags: r, storage, xts, rdata

this maybe a very simple issue, but i cannot seem to path through it. When i try to load a file i have in my directory, by assigning "Q1", it creates a Value Q1 = data.US and a weird name in the Data tab data.US where the actual table is reflected.

`Q1 <- load(file = "data_all_2011Q1.RData" )`

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3KxZ.png)

My expectation would be that the table will be loaded into Data Workstation with name Q1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.RData` files store R objects, together with their names. You can see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) that `load` returns a list of names of variables that are loaded. Therefore your object `Q1` only contains `"data.US"`, because that is the name of the object in the `.RData` file. The `data.US` object is created in your environment because that is the object stored in the `.RData`  file.

It is better to use `.RDS` files for storing single objects. See the following example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)

save(x,file='x.RData')
rm('x')
y<-load('x.RData')
# object y does not contain our vector x, it just contains the name of that variable: "x".
# However, our object x is loaded into our environment.


x <- c(1,2,3)
saveRDS(x,file="x.RDS")
rm('x')
y<-readRDS('x.RDS')
# object y contains our vector x, as desired.
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, this is clear now. I was surprise because i obtained 3 files for an assignement and it seems that all these 3 files have all the same name data.US, but different data inside, hence my confusion.